# How to avoid using a raw type as a generic parameter when Class<T> is needed

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class that looks like this:

```java
abstract class Handler<T> {

    Handler(Class<T> clazz) {
        // ...
    }

    abstract void handle(T object);

}
```

I'm trying to extent it, where `T` is a type with a wildcard generic parameter (for the sake of the example, say `List<?>`). What I want to be able to do is something like:

```java
class MyHandler extends Handler<List<?>> {
    MyHandler() {
        super(List.class); 
     // ^ Compiler error: The constructor Handler<List<?>>(Class<List>) is undefined
     // super(List<?>.class); is also a compiler error
    }

    void handle(List<?> object) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell the above is totally safe, so I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't allow it. My current solution involves the use of raw types, unsafe casting and suppression of the warnings and seems like it can't be solution the language intends me to use:

```java
class MyHandler extends Handler<List> { // Warning: List is a raw type
    MyHandler() {
        super(List.class); 
    }

    void handle(List objectRaw) { // Warning: List is a raw type
        List<?> object = (List<?>) objectRaw;
        // ...
    }
}
```

This needs to be a singleton so I can't add generic parameters to `MyHandler`. How do I avoid all these bad practices (raw types and the cast)? Theres no reason this should be unsafe and I'm having a hard time believing there's no way to do this in Java.

Comment: What does `Handler` do with that `Class` instance?

Comment: @tgdavies Shouldn't really matter to the question, but it's looking for some annotations and some meta-info like the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by casting the class object to type `Class<List<?>>` in the `MyHandler` constructor:

```
MyHandler() {
    super((Class<List<?>>) (Object) List.class); 
}
```

#### The problem

The problem is that there is no simple way in Java to express a class literal of type `Class<List<?>>`. `List.class` has type `Class<List>`.

I think there are situations where it would not be safe to the second type to the first one, but in your code there is probable no problem at all.

If, for example, your code uses `clazz` to check the runtime type of objects using `isAssignableFrom` you might get it trouble.

#### Type token

If you use some type-token implementation instead of a `java.lang.Class`, for example the one in Guava, you will be able to express a literal of the exact right type:

```
abstract class Handler<T> {
    Handler(TypeToken<T> clazz) {
        // ...
    }

    abstract void handle(T object);
}

class MyHandler extends Handler<List<?>> {
    MyHandler() {
        super(new TypeToken<List<?>>() {}); 
    }

    void handle(List<?> object) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass a class object to the `Handler` constructor.

```
abstract class Handler<T> {
    final Class<T> clazz;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Handler(T... dummy) {
        if (dummy == null || dummy.length > 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Do not specify the 'dummy' argument");
        clazz = (Class<T>) dummy.getClass().componentType();
        System.out.println("Handler clazz=" + clazz);
    }

    abstract void handle(T object);

}

class MyHandler extends Handler<List<Integer>> {
    void handle(List<Integer> object) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
MyHandler mh = new MyHandler();
```

output

```
Handler clazz=interface java.util.List
```

You can also implement anonymous inner classes.

```
Handler<String> h = new Handler<>() {
    @Override
    void handle(String object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
```

output

```
Handler clazz=class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Cool trick! An implicit super-constructor call with an empty var-args array! Might be a little too tricky, tough...

Comment: And you ARE pretty good at English.

Comment: I think Lii's answer is more appropriate for he problem, but still a +1 this is a really cool trick